# ms c++ get pid of current process

Tags: c++, windows, process, pid

Parts of my application are in C++ under windows. I need the process id for the current process. Any thoughts?

Comment: I first read it as "get rid of current process" :)

Comment: @Otherside made me look in vocabulary

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [`GetCurrentProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180(VS.85).aspx) function will do this.

Comment: There is also `_getpid()` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2y34y40%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: `_getpid()` just calls `GetCurrentProcessId()`. There is only one process id, and the lowest level function that returns it is `GetCurrentProcessId()`.

Answer (score 7):

Having grown accustomed to seeing yards and yards of code to accomplish seemingly straightforward tasks, I was pleasantly surprised at the directness of `GetCurrentProcessId`. Earlier today, I watched it run in a debugger, when I was following a new bit of code in a `DllMain` routine that combines the process ID with an embedded GUID to create a locally unique name for a mutex.

Following is the entire routine, all three machine instructions.

```
mov         eax,fs:[00000018]
mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+20h]
ret
```

BTW, two other blessedly simple Windows API functions are `GetLastError` and `SetLastError`; indeed, both are quite similar to this one.

Comment: I forgot to mention in that "short, sweet" group is GetProcessHeap.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getpid()` or `_getpid()` , which are defined in `<process.h>` library.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getpid?view=vs-2019

Comment: As Greg Hewgill already mentioned under the accepted answer, `_getpid()` just calls `GetCurrentProcessId()`, which is the lowest level function that returns the process id.

Comment: Actually before I write this answer, I tried `GetCurrentProcessId()` but I couldn't run it, because I had not included `<windows.h>` library, which was not mentioned in the previous answer. 

After some tries I got it.