# Unmanaged C++ Get the current process id? (Console Application)

Tags: c++, winapi, process

How can I get the current process id from an unmanaged C++ console application? I see that

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId
```

Works when you have an HWND, but what can I do for a console application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `GetCurrentProcessId`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180(VS.85).aspx

Comment: That would make sense. Not quite sure how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GetCurrentProcessId

Exact same question?
[Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298257/ms-c-get-pid-of-current-process)

In unix you can go:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t getpid(void);
pid_t getppid(void);
```

DESCRIPTION
getpid() returns the process ID of the current process. (This is often
used by routines that generate unique temporary filenames.)