# How to add the Process id to a LOG4J log file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j, pattern-layout

I currently have the below pattern layout in log4j.  I want to add the Process id to the log file.  How can I do it?

```
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Pasted sample log message

```
2011-01-07 11:48:21,940 [main] INFO  Testing1
2011-01-07 11:48:21,942 [main] INFO  Test.common.ApplicationProperties - Used log4j
```

---

log4j.properties

```
"log4j.properties" [Read only] 26 lines, 884 characters
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout, A1

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}  %-5p  (%c) %m%n


log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.A1.File=/homw/cus/logs/ccl.02.log
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=40


log4j.category.test.common.DBConnectionPool=WARN
log4j.category.test.common.DataBaseHandler=WARN
log4j.category.test.cttg.tables=WARN
log4j.category.test.middleware.tables=WARN

log4j.logger.org.apache.axis=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina=ERROR
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to log Process id using Log4cxx or log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286089/how-to-log-process-id-using-log4cxx-or-log4j)

Comment: Are you wanting to have the java process ID printed, or the current thread ID printed?

Answer (score 22):

You should use [MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) to do it

In the config file :

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}  %-5p  (%c) %m%n %X{PID}
```

`%X{PID}` is used to match the context value *PID*

And then, in the code, before the logging begins :

log4j 1.x

```
RuntimeMXBean rt = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
String pid = rt.getName();
MDC.put("PID", pid);
```

log4j 2.x

```
RuntimeMXBean rt = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
String pid = rt.getName();
ThreadContext.put("PID", pid);
```

Comment: I am trying to run your code in wso2 esb in script mediator like this but it is giving an error. importPackage(Packages.java.net);    
importPackage(java.lang.management);
importPackage(Packages.org.apache.log4j);        
try {            
 RuntimeMXBean rt = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
String pid = rt.getName();
MDC.put("PID", pid);        
}
} catch (e) {        }

Comment: WSo2 EsB does not allow me to save the change. it gives a proxy admin exception,if i remove this script mediator and change something else, the service works fine. I think there is something wrong with code, maybe i am not including the right packages or "script" mediator takes "javascript" as input and this may be does not allowed in java script.

Comment: I don't know at all WSo2 EsB. In a regular java file, here are the import : `import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory; import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean; import org.apache.log4j.MDC;`

Comment: its not that , i have to use javascript to pick the value, then use it for logging because there is not pre defined log4j specifier to pick up the pid...

Comment: @omerkhalid I think you should create a question of your own, specifying exactly what you are doing and what you want to do.

Comment: @ToYonos, since Log4j 2.9.0 (cf. [LOG4J2-1884](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1884)) there is a pattern to print the process id: `%pid` (cf. [patterns documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#patterns))

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of doing it using standard Java classes. Generally process ID is appended at file level not at the log level. And [here](http://www.theresearchkitchen.com/blog/archives/100) (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180705112944/http://www.theresearchkitchen.com/archives/100)) is an example of doing it.

Comment: i have only log4j.properites file. I dont see any xml config file.

Comment: In the weblink you have pasted there is a config xml file

Comment: I dont see any config xml file. Where can i make the change

Comment: I have the below property file

Comment: Edited my question and pasted the property file that i have

Comment: @Arav, you can either use log4j.properties or log4j.xml for your configuration

Comment: Appending the process id at the file level is quite useless for cron jobs. In the worst case this will create every minute a new file.

Answer (score 1):

With the following pattern, showing threadID and class. If you want to see the Process ID, might check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754933/log4j2-include-pid)

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.conversionPattern=%-5p %d{ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t:%c] %m%n
```

I managed to do so, but I have several appenders, one for each part of the application, like the following:

```
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, SYSLOG2
log4j.logger.com.myself.logic=DEBUG, SYSLOG
log4j.logger.com.myself.database=DEBUG, SYSLOG3
log4j.logger.com.myself.other=DEBUG, SYSLOG
```

Here are some examples of generated logs, to check if this is what you require:

```
INFO 20012015 11:56:17.318 [pool-1-thread-1:com.myself.logic.MonitoringTask] 10602: Validation of orders before UTC=2015-01-20T16:56:17
INFO 20012015 11:56:34.200 [main:com.gmv.pazgs.mus.mpu.CLibWrapper] 10402: MPU Library folder: xxxxx
INFO 20012015 11:56:34.209 [main:com.gmv.pazgs.mus.mpu.CLibWrapper] 10402: MPU Configuration folder: xxxxx
INFO 20012015 11:56:34.773 [main:com.gmv.pazgs.mus.mpu.CLibWrapper] 10402: Calling InitLeap()
INFO 20012015 11:56:34.786 [main:com.gmv.pazgs.mus.mpu.CLibWrapper] 10402: Calling InitFourier()
INFO 20012015 11:57:10.151 [CRON_Thread:com.myself.other.DTOLDispatcher] 10202: Times to send: [11:00, 23:00] - current time = Tue Jan 20 11:57:10 UTC 2015
INFO 20012015 11:58:10.165 [pool-1-thread-4:com.myself.logic.MonitoringTask] 10602: Executing Monitoring Task UTC=2015-01-20T11:58:10
INFO 20012015 11:58:10.171 [pool-1-thread-5:com.myself.logic.OrderValidationTask] 10602: Executing OrderValidationTask UTC=2015-01-20T11:58:10
INFO 20012015 11:58:10.291 [CRON_Thread:com.myself.other.DTOLDispatcher] 10202: Times to send: [11:00, 23:00] - current time = Tue Jan 20 11:58:10 UTC 2015
INFO 20012015 11:58:10.684 [pool-1-thread-4:com.myself.logic.MonitoringTask] 10602: Expiration of orders before UTC=2015-01-20T11:58:10
INFO 20012015 11:58:11.218 [pool-1-thread-4:com.myself.logic.MonitoringTask] 10602: checking orders for suppresed status before UTC=2015-01-20T11:58:11
INFO 20012015 11:58:11.244 [pool-1-thread-4:com.myself.logic.MonitoringTask] 10602: Validation of orders before UTC=2015-01-20T16:58:11
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i needed the Process id, i am already using thread id.