# Having DSpace applications log into separate log files

Tags: logging, log4j, dspace

We use DSpace `dspace-5.4`.

DSpace 5's Maven-Ant build and installation process produces a single `log4j.properties` file, which is used by each DSpace application.

For example, the *xmlui* and *oai* servlets and each *./dspace* invocation take the same `log4j.properties` file and therefore write to the same log files. This means that a log file such as `$DSPACE_INSTALL_DIR/log/dspace.log` is concurrently being written to by different processes. This makes reading the log files complicated on busy installations.

Is there a pragmatic way to filter out a particular log-writing DSpace process from DSpace's log files, or have dedicated log files for each process (e.g. `dspace-xmlui.log`)?

I have already added a *thread* marker into my *log4j* patterns:

```
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c : %t - %m%n
```

[There seems to be a way of augmenting *log4j* log entries with process identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27961334/923560), though I cannot say where it would be best to add such kind of log4j initial configuration during DSpace's initialization.