# Why some information missing after switching from logback to log4j?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, logback

It was necessary to change from logback to log4j, I modified pom for this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And 'log4j.properties' file was added:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,Console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n
```

But in result, there are different logs. With logback I have something like this:

```
2022-11-15 18:43:05.819  INFO 13700 --- [           main] en.main.com.Application                   : Starting Application using Java 11.0.14 on '' with PID 13700
2022-11-15 18:43:06.710  INFO 13700 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope      : BeanFactory id=eb6a152f-721c-3012-b9ce-880d2bbbe06c
2022-11-15 18:43:06.967  INFO 13700 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer   : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2022-11-15 18:43:06.974  INFO 13700 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService    : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-11-15 18:43:06.974  INFO 13700 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.53]
2022-11-15 18:43:07.158  INFO 13700 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/main]    : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-11-15 18:43:07.159  INFO 13700 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext  : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1298 ms
2022-11-15 18:43:07.898  INFO 13700 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer   : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path '/main'
2022-11-15 18:43:07.985  INFO 13700 --- [           main] en.main.com.Application                   : Started Application in 2.648 seconds (JVM running for 3.726)
```

And after log4j:

```
2022-11-15 18:38:00,817 INFO  - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
2022-11-15 18:38:00,818 INFO  - Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-11-15 18:38:00,818 INFO  - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.53]
2022-11-15 18:38:01,057 INFO  - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-11-15 18:38:02,890 INFO  - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
2022-11-15 18:38:03,001 INFO  - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-11-15 18:38:03,318 INFO  - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-11-15 18:38:03,340 INFO  - HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2022-11-15 18:38:03,397 INFO  - HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
```

I can't understand why a part of useful information is missing. Also tried to display some transactions info, by adding

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager=DEBUG
```

but there is no result.

Comment: It's following the "conversionPattern" that you specified in the config. If you want it to be different, then change the pattern.

Comment: @Michael thx for your comment, I tried to change the "conversionPattern" and even delete it, but I still can't see messages in the log about the PID and the start time of the application, as it was in the logback.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622252/how-to-add-the-process-id-to-a-log4j-log-file

Comment: @grekier  in that topic, the message format is also considered, in my case some information has completely disappeared, i.e. there are no whole messages